# Count the number of iterations of a if loop

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I have the following if loop:

```
for line in content[:-1]:
 # if the line has No Data in it
    if line.find("No Data"):
        line = line.replace("No Data", "0")
```

What the if loop does is to read every line of a list called "Content" and whe it detects the words "No Data" it subtitutes them for a Zero value. What I would like to do is to Count how many times this Change is done; I've tried with the following:

```
ctr=0
for line in content[:-1]:
    if line.find("No Data"):
        line = line.replace("No Data", "0")
        ctr +=1
```

But what I got is that crt equals the total value of lines instead the number of times that that Change is done.

Comment: is there more than one instance of "No Data" per line?

Comment: "But what I got is that crt equals the total value of lines instead the number of times that that Change is done." - Maybe all lines contains 'No Data' ?

Comment: If you really indented your code as you show it here, it should work as you intended.

Comment: Doesn't `.find()` return `-1` if the string is not found, so would still satisfy the `if` statement?

Comment: No, not every line contains 'No Data'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.find` returns the *position* of the string if found or `-1`. So:

`if line.find("No Data")` is `True` when:

- not found (because worth `-1`)
- data not at the start of the line

It is `False` when data is in the string but at the start of the line.

It's a classic mistake to make. Solution: don't use `find` as you don't care about the position of the data, just do:

```
if "No data" in line:
```

Answer (score 0):

`if line.find("No Data")` will always be true. Just replace it `if line.find("No Data") is not -1`

You can also use the [`in` operator](https://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details):

```
if "No Data" in line: 
    #do stuff
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If there is more than one instance of "No Data" in a line, and you want to count the total number of replacements made, as opposed to the number of lines which have atleast one replacement:

using the `count` function:

```
ctr=0
for line in content[:-1]:
    if line.count("No Data") > 0:
        line = line.replace("No Data", "0")
        ctr += line.count("No Data")
```

performed in lambdas:

```
ctr = sum([line.count('No Data') for line in content[:-1]])
content = [line.replace("No Data", 0) for line in content[:-1]]
```

if you just want to find the number of lines that have "No Data", then use the `in` conditional:

```
ctr=0
for line in content[:-1]:
    if "No Data" in line:
        line = line.replace("No Data", "0")
        ctr += 1
```

alternatively:

```
ctr = len([line for line in content[:-1] if "No Data" in line])
content = [line.replace("No Data", 0) for line in content[:-1]]
```